# Remote connect to Elasticsearch running in Kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-data-elasticsearch

I've Elasticsearch running on Kubernetes cluster (exposed using NodePort)

```
helm install --name my-elasticsearch stable/elasticsearch
kubectl get svc
my-elasticsearch-client                  NodePort       10.123.40.199     <none>        9200:31429/TCP               107m
my-elasticsearch-discovery               ClusterIP      None             <none>        9300/TCP                     107m
```

I'm trying to connect it remotely from my spring boot app running in my IDE.

My Spring boot `application.properties`
Note I'm using a K8s Host IP and the my-elasticsearch-client NodePort

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=elasticsearch
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=10.123.45.147:31429
spring.data.elasticsearch.repositories.enabled=true
```

I can also reach cluster-node in the http://10.134.39.147:31429/ in browser

```
{
  "name" : "my-elasticsearch-client-797bc4dff6-wz2gq",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "Js3zbqs_SJikVb42ZLGvpw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.5.1",
    "build_flavor" : "oss",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "8c58350",
    "build_date" : "2018-11-16T02:22:42.182257Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.5.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

GET _cluster/health

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 7,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 2,
  "active_primary_shards" : 6,
  "active_shards" : 12,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 100.0
}
```

**The problem** is I'm hitting *org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available*

I can confirm Elasticsearch is up cause I can access data via Kibana running on same cluster.

```
2019-02-06 16:25:46.936  INFO 66980 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.e.c.TransportClientFactoryBean     : Adding transport node : 10.123.45.147:31429
2019-02-06 16:26:18.330  INFO 66980 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2019-02-06 16:26:18.343 ERROR 66980 --- [  restartedMain] .d.e.r.s.AbstractElasticsearchRepository : failed to load elasticsearch nodes : org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{mT2_e3FzSTiDu3UHzRbOVg}{10.123.45.147}{10.123.45.147:31429}]
2019-02-06 16:26:18.536  INFO 66980 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-02-06 16:26:18.744  INFO 66980 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2019-02-06 16:26:18.794  INFO 66980 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-02-06 16:26:18.796  INFO 66980 --- [  restartedMain] c.a.o.c.CustomerJourneyApplication       : Started CustomerJourneyApplication in 35.786 seconds (JVM running for 37.054)
hello world, I have just started up
2019-02-06 16:26:18.861 ERROR 66980 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{mT2_e3FzSTiDu3UHzRbOVg}{10.123.45.147}{10.123.45.147:31429}]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:349) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:247) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:60) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:381) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:407) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:396) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:46) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.index(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:577) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.save(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:156) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.index(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:175) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.index(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.avaya.oceana.customerjourney.service.JourneyService.putJourney(JourneyService.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.avaya.oceana.customerjourney.CustomerJourneyApplication.addJourneys(CustomerJourneyApplication.java:81) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.avaya.oceana.customerjourney.CustomerJourneyApplication.doSomethingAfterStartup(CustomerJourneyApplication.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:259) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:179) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:142) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:398) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:355) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.running(EventPublishingRunListener.java:105) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.running(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:78) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:332) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at com.avaya.oceana.customerjourney.CustomerJourneyApplication.main(CustomerJourneyApplication.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]

2019-02-06 16:26:18.864  INFO 66980 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.

The Elasticsearch Client `TransportClient` that `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` autoconfigures is deprecated. It gets auto configured by and needs to connect to the 9300 "transport" API. But this is a headless service for internal Kubernetes discovery and there's no way of exposing it.

So, I've switched to the newer `RestHighLevelClient`:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.3/java-rest-high.html

Also, I needed to disable this `management.health.elasticsearch.enabled=false` since it was trying to connect to an elasticsearh on localhost??

I just need to figure out if `RestHighLevelClient` can be used by spring-data `ElasticsearchRepository`